# Runnable won't stop when using a BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, runnable

I have a Runnable that won't stop even though the conditions are set to stop. Not sure why it's happening. Sometimes a few Threads are still alive other are not. I've left it run for over an hour to see if it would stop but it doesn't. Does it have something with the way I'm passing arguments?

```
public class ParserWorker implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<String> queue = null;
    private ZipReader zip = null;

    public ParserWorker(BlockingQueue<String> queue, ZipReader zip) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!queue.isEmpty() || !zip.isClosed()) {
                String line = queue.take();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class that starts everything.

```
public Start() throws InterruptedException   {
    File zipFile = new File("C:\\development\\data2.zip");
    BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(1024);

    ZipReader zip = new ZipReader(queue, zipFile);

    ParserWorker w1 = new ParserWorker(queue, zip);
    ParserWorker w2 = new ParserWorker(queue, zip);
    ParserWorker w3 = new ParserWorker(queue, zip);
    ParserWorker w4 = new ParserWorker(queue, zip);

    //Start reading zip file
    Thread zipThread = new Thread(zip);
    zipThread.start();

    //Give a little pause to allow the queue to fill
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    //Starts the Consumable Threads
    Thread t1 = new Thread(w1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(w2);
    Thread t3 = new Thread(w3);
    Thread t4 = new Thread(w4);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();

    //waits until the zip file is closed.
    while (!zip.isClosed()) {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    //By this point the Zip file is closed, queue may still contain items
    System.out.println("Queue isEmpty:" + queue.isEmpty() + ", Zip isClosed:" + zip.isClosed());

    //Waits until the Queue is empty
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    //By this point the Zip file is closed and the queue is empty.
    System.out.println("Queue isEmpty:" + queue.isEmpty() + ", Zip isClosed:" + zip.isClosed());

    while (t1.isAlive() || t2.isAlive() || t3.isAlive() || t4.isAlive()) {
        System.out.println("T1 alive:" + t1.isAlive() + ", T2 alive:" + t2.isAlive() + ",T3 alive:" + t3.isAlive() + ",T4 alive:" + t4.isAlive());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }


    System.out.println("Done");
```

I've included the ZipReader for clarification.

```
public class ZipReader implements Runnable{

    private boolean closed = true;
    private File zipFileName = null;

    protected BlockingQueue<String> queue = null;

    public ZipReader(BlockingQueue<String> queue, File zipFileName) {
        this.queue = queue; 
        this.zipFileName = zipFileName;
    }

    public boolean isClosed() {
        return closed;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      String line = null;
      long index = 1L;
      ZipFile zipFile = null;

      try {
            System.out.println("Opening Zip file");
            zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFileName);
            closed = false;
            System.out.println("Getting entries");
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                ZipEntry zipEntryObj = entries.nextElement();
                System.out.println("Processing file: " + zipEntryObj.getName());
                InputStream input = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntryObj);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(input);

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
//                    if (index++ % 10000 == 0) {
//                        System.out.println("Index:" + index);
//                    }
//                    System.out.println(line);
                    queue.put(line);
                }
                br.close();
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Closing zip file");
            try {
                if (zipFile != null) {
                    zipFile.close();
                }
                closed = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Here is the output I get.

```
Opening Zip file
Getting entries
Processing file: data01.txt
Processing file: data02.txt
Processing file: data03.txt
Processing file: data04.txt
Processing file: data05.txt
Processing file: data06.txt
Processing file: data07.txt
Processing file: data08.txt
Processing file: data09.txt
Processing file: data10.txt
Closing zip file
Queue isEmpty:true, Zip isClosed:true
Queue isEmpty:true, Zip isClosed:true
T1 alive:true, T2 alive:true,T3 alive:true,T4 alive:true
T1 alive:true, T2 alive:true,T3 alive:true,T4 alive:true
T1 alive:true, T2 alive:true,T3 alive:true,T4 alive:true
T1 alive:true, T2 alive:true,T3 alive:true,T4 alive:true
T1 alive:true, T2 alive:true,T3 alive:true,T4 alive:true
T1 alive:true, T2 alive:true,T3 alive:true,T4 alive:true
T1 alive:true, T2 alive:true,T3 alive:true,T4 alive:true
T1 alive:true, T2 alive:true,T3 alive:true,T4 alive:true
T1 alive:true, T2 alive:true,T3 alive:true,T4 alive:true
T1 alive:true, T2 alive:true,T3 alive:true,T4 alive:true
```

Comment: Looks like you never close "zip" so "zip.isClosed()" will always be false

Comment: I've included the ZipReader class, I believe that it is closed when file end is reached.

Comment: Try printing to see whether your assumption is correct or not.

Comment: Where is the definition of your `zip.isEmpty()` method? Or you meant `queue.isEmpty()`?

Comment: @IvayloToskov - made the correction. thanks.

Comment: Does it sometimes terminate, or never?

Comment: I have never had all 4 threads terminate. I have had 1 or 2 threads terminate.

Comment: Can you somehow share the contents of the `zip` file?

Comment: Data file is accessible here. http://cloud.geekydaddy.ca/index.php/s/eXEMSPjStauOmJc

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies in your `while` loop within the `ParserWorker` class. What I refer to is:

```
while (!queue.isEmpty() || !zip.isClosed()) {
  String line = queue.take();
}
```

With this code you have concurrency issues. When the `take` method of `BlockingQueue` is invoked, two things may happen:

1. If the queue is not empty, the thread will get the next element in a synchronized manner. This means that no two threads can get the same element.
2. If the queue is empty, the thread will wait until an element is put.

The problem with your code is that you assume that `String line = queue.take();` and `!queue.isEmpty()` are executed at the same time with no concurrency issues. However, the following may(and in your case does) happen:

1. There is a single element in the queue.
2. Two threads check if `!queue.isEmpty()` at the same time. For both threads the return value is `true`, since the queue is not empty.
3. The first(the faster) thread calls `queue.take()` and gets this single element, then checks again the `while` condition and terminates, since the queue is yet empty.
4. The second(the slower) threads invokes `queue.take()` on an empty queue, since the first thread has already taken the element from the queue. For this reason the thread blocks until a new element is put on the queue. However, at certain point this never happens in your scenario, since all of the lines are read. This means that the thread is blocked forever, since there is no other thread that will put an element for it.

There are plenty of solutions to fix that. A simple one will be to change

```
while (t1.isAlive() || t2.isAlive() || t3.isAlive() || t4.isAlive()) {
  System.out.println("T1 alive:" + t1.isAlive() + ", T2 alive:" + t2.isAlive() + ",T3 alive:" + t3.isAlive() + ",T4 alive:" + t4.isAlive());
  Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

to

```
while (t1.isAlive() || t2.isAlive() || t3.isAlive() || t4.isAlive()) {
  System.out.println("T1 alive:" + t1.isAlive() + ", T2 alive:" + t2.isAlive() + ",T3 alive:" + t3.isAlive() + ",T4 alive:" + t4.isAlive());
  queue.put("");
  Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

With the line `queue.put("");` you ensure that elements will be put until all of the threads terminate. This will be executed at most 3 times in your case. It is not the most proper solution and makes your threads read empty strings, but it is the simplest one. You can spent some time to come up with other synchronization that suits your needs if this does not work.

Another solution may use additional synchronization using the queue as a lock:

```
while (!queue.isEmpty() || !zip.isClosed()) {
  synchronized (queue) {
    if(!queue.isEmpty()) {
      String line = queue.take();
    }
  }
}
```

In this way it is ensured that the check if the queue is empty and taking an element in case it's not are executed together for each thread, so that no thread will try to pop an empty queue. You have to decide which approach you prefer. The second one requires additional synchronization, but won't force your threads to pop empty strings.

Comment: Thanks, I just included the ZipReader class for clarification. You'll notice that when the file end is reached, in the 'finally' statement the 'closed' is set to 'true'

Comment: Instead of using `queue.take()` I decided to use `queue.poll()` and handle the null.

Comment: Thanks for you help. This clarified a lot for me.